# Success : Successful :: Failure : _____________

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, vocabulary

Is there an adjective to describe "full of failure(s)"?  Most often heard it's that s.o./s.t. ***is*** a failure, but I'm looking specifically for an adjective.

**Edit**:  I'm looking for a word that encompasses an ongoing pattern of failure, not just a one-time event.  Note that while possible, "*unsuccessful*" doesn't usually imply failure.

> She married her childhood sweetheart, built a profitable multi-national corporation, and founded several humanitarian NPOs.  What a **successful** woman!

vs.

> She ran out on her family.  She was arrested for embezzling millions from her own company; ousted by the board of directors.  Then she blew all of her savings on gambling and drugs.  What a **_____________** woman!

I feel like "*failed*" and "*unsuccessful*" don't correctly capture the weight of this context.  You could say "*failure of*", but that's not an adjective.

Comment: For single word requests, we need a sample sentence into which the word will fit. See the Tour for details.

Comment: How about "failed"?

Comment: @NigelJ:  Sorry, posted from Android app, and I couldn't find the Tour in there.  I'll update.

Comment: Perhaps *hopeless* or *worthless*.

Comment: Note that culpability is indicated in your example sentence, whereas 'success' (at least from a worldly point of view) can depend on circumstances, 'chance', and not just (or even not) merit.

Comment: Would **failing** capture any more of the weight you want?

Comment: @ermanen:  You missed the point of my question.  Of course I could say that, but I'm specifically wondering if there is an adjective for that.

Answer (score 2):

*Updated to reflect question clarification*

From your provided example, it seems as if you're trying to connote a moral judgement on the 2nd woman. In this case, *degenerate* might suit you. From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/degenerate):

> Having sunk to a condition below that which is normal to a type; *especially* having sunk to a lower and usually corrupt and vicious state.

*She ran out on her family. She was arrested...What a **degenerate** woman!*

If you don't want to necessarily give such a moral judgement, I think [hopeless](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hopeless) might be more of what you're after (emphasis mine):

> Having no expecation of good **or success**

as in, *she ran out on her family. She was arrested...What a **hopeless** woman!*

Comment: A successful mission and a failed mission.

Answer (score 1):

**Pauperized**

> [pauperize](https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=jNheXdiYG6Pgz7sPgcSQwAk&q=pauperized%20meaning&oq=&gs_l=mobile-gws-wiz-hp.1.3.41i70i249j41j41i71j41i70i249j41l3j41i22i30.0.0..5516...0.0..0.0.0.......0...........8.8xqqAQa7xOc)
>
> verb
>
> past tense: pauperized; past participle: pauperized
>
> make very poor; impoverish.

Or,

> **[impoverished](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/impoverished)**
>
> adjective
>
> very poor:
>
> made weaker or worse in quality

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but see expanded question.

Comment: “What a vain woman!” definitely won’t work. “What a futile woman” just sounds odd.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the context. 'Buggy' or 'faulty' work for applications and engineering. For a person, 'hopeless' or 'relentlessly/consistently unsuccessful'.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please note that this is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum, and answers are expected to explain, not merely state— *why* do you propose these terms? What are some examples of their usage? What does the dictionary say about them? I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Answer (score 0):

I searched for antonyms of successful, and the two I think convey the meaning you want are hopeless and unfortunate.

EDIT = I moved my second comment to here.

You could also use miserable or pathetic, but the first carries a sense of judgement and the second an air if disrespect and maybe even hatred. Depending on context, it may be best to last out the facts that will lead the reader to the conclusion you want them to make. As Brad Pitt told Matt Damon in Ocean's 11, never use seven words when four will do.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use miserable or pathetic, but the first carries a sense of judgement and the second an air if disrespect and maybe even hatred. Depending on context, it may be best to last out the facts that will lead the reader to the conclusion you want them to make. As Brad Pitt told Matt Damon in Ocean's 11, never use seven words when four will do.